# $state.go not working with angularjs 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want configure the routing at my app angularjs this is my app.js

In my app.js I have two chlidren login and home bu default I have loginComponent
and then when I click on button login I replace the login view by home view

and I have an error $state is not defined

```
   import AppComponent from './app.component';
    import LoginComponent from './login/login.component';
    import HomeComponent from './home/home.component';

    import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

angular.module('app', [
  uiRouter
])
  .config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)=> {
    "ngInject";
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        component: 'login'
      });
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        component: 'home'
      });
  })
  .component('app', AppComponent)
  .component('home', HomeComponent)
  .component('login', LoginComponent);
```

this is my login.controller

```
class LoginController {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'login';
    console.log('login controller');
  }
  openHome(){
    console.log("uo");
    $state.go('home');
  }
}

export default LoginController;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here, but don't you have to pass in the $state dependency into your class?

Comment: should I import it ?

Comment: If you want to use it, you need to inject it. I've never injected with ES6 syntax so that's something you'll have to look up

Comment: this is a version its compatible with $state.go     "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.0-beta.1",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you need to inject `$state` into `LoginController`.

```
class LoginController {
  constructor($state) {
    this.name = 'login';
    this.$state = $state;
    console.log('login controller');
  }
  openHome(){
    console.log("uo");
    this.$state.go('home');
  }
}

LoginController.$inject = ['$state'];

export default LoginController;
```

Or you can use something like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)