# Know which syntax use with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

firstly this is my devDependencies

```
 "angular": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
```

I want to develope with angularjs version which use component and controller as class and for routing I dont know which syntax to use

I need to know my dependencies is compatible with wich syntax espacially for routing if some one can give me an exmaple for routing

```
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

angular.module('app', [
  uiRouter
])
  .config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)=> {
    "ngInject";
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        component: 'login'
      });
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        component: 'home'
      });
  })
```

but I got error when I tried to use $state.go('home') in my controller 
thanks for helping

**UPDATE**

LoginController

```
class LoginController {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'login';
    console.log('login controller');
  }
  openHome(){
    console.log("uo");
    $state.go('home');
  }
}

export default LoginController;
```

login.js

```
import LoginComponent from './login.component'
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

angular.module('login',[
  uiRouter

])
  .config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)=> {
    "ngInject";
  })
.component('login',LoginComponent);
```

**after adding $scope and $state in constructor**

[image]

Comment: show us code of your controller. What is the content of your error also ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148086/state-go-not-working-with-angularjs-1-5

Comment: Are you injecting $state into your controller?

Comment: updating my question

Comment: Can you setup a JSfiddle or a plunker reproducing your issue?

Comment: ok I will do that

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Utlz7X7UnYbKUwlDeWtH?p=preview

Comment: Must be the wrong link, I can't see your `LoginController` or any issue related to your question in this one.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/L4Tsr2lQUkijQstuCEPR?p=catalogue 

here is the plunker correct

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes from your controller. Try this :

LoginController :

```
'use strict';
(function(){

class LoginController {
  constructor($state) {

this.openHome = function(){
    console.log("uo");
    $state.go('home');
  }

}

angular.module('app')
  .component('login', {
    templateUrl: 'your/location/toMyFile.html',
    controller: LoginComponent
  });

})();
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I heared that $scope is no longer used in the latest version ?